# Unable to install service fabric runtime

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powershell, azure-service-fabric

### Update

By looking at the processes under Task Manager, I was able to locate the installer for Service Fabric Runtime (the first of the two components that are attempted installed below, and apparently the one that fails).

I found the file and tried to run it from Powershell (after first removing the Service Fabric folder that had been created during my previous attempt). The result is shown below: Apparently it starts the installation process, then freezes and stops, and times out after 10 minutes with no further explanation.

```
c:\Appl>MicrosoftServiceFabric.8.2.1363.9590.exe /accepteula /force
20.01.2022 08:26:11,Info,Installing Service Fabric Runtime. Logs written to C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\InstallFabricRuntime_637782675714458610.log
20.01.2022 08:26:11,Info,Running extract in parallel.
20.01.2022 08:26:11,Info,Unpackaging autoextractor...
20.01.2022 08:26:11,Info,20.01.2022 09:26:11 Running Process: powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser with timeout 00:01:00
20.01.2022 08:26:12,Info,Creating temporary runtime directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.pxl3wsxg.zi0.
20.01.2022 08:26:12,Info,Extracting runtime cab to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.pxl3wsxg.zi0...
20.01.2022 08:26:12,Info,20.01.2022 09:26:12 Running Process: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MicrosoftServiceFabricAutoextractor.exe /L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.pxl3wsxg.zi0" /E /Y with timeout 01:00:00
20.01.2022 08:26:12,Info,Current Powershell Execution Policy: Unrestricted
20.01.2022 08:26:12,Info,Searching for legacy installation registry key.
20.01.2022 08:26:12,Info,Service Fabric Product not detected in registry.
20.01.2022 08:26:18,Info,Successfully extracted cab file to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.pxl3wsxg.zi0
20.01.2022 08:26:18,Info,Moving FabricRoot files from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.pxl3wsxg.zi0' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric'.
20.01.2022 08:26:18,Info,Moved FabricRoot files 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric' successfully.
20.01.2022 08:26:18,Info,Installing Service Fabric Runtime... Logs written to: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog_637782675714458610.log
20.01.2022 08:26:18,Info,Executing powershell.exe with parameters: -NoProfile -Command & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\InstallFabric.ps1' -FabricRootIsPreInstalled -AcceptEULA -LogPath C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog_637782675714458610.log
20.01.2022 08:26:18,Info,20.01.2022 09:26:18 Running Process: powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\InstallFabric.ps1' -FabricRootIsPreInstalled -AcceptEULA -LogPath C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog_637782675714458610.log with timeout 00:10:00
20.01.2022 08:36:18,Error,Timeout 00:10:00 exceeded, terminating process..
20.01.2022 08:36:18,Error,Unable to install Service Fabric Runtime using C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\InstallFabric.ps1. ExitCode: -1. Find additional logs at: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog_637782675714458610.log.
```

---

#### Original question:

I'm not sure if this is a valid question for SO, as it relates to the setup of a dev tool/system, rather than a programming question directly, but I hope you'll let it pass, as I think it might be useful for other programmers too:

(*Note, full disclosure: I've also registered this same question as an issue under the [Service Fabric GitHub Repository](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1307#issue-1107996432). If I get an answer there that helps solve the problem, I'll naturally add it here too*).

---

#### Failing to install Service Fabric SDK

This is on Windows 10 (version 10.0.19044)

I downloaded the installer from the offical site ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started ) and ran it, as I've done previously on a different PC with no issues.

#### The result this time was as follows:

[image: 02_err]

Looking at the **last** of the two logs, I get (among other stuff) this:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 8.2.1363'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\*MyUserName*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_8_2_CU1\B9FBB56A2D94EADC21BE8863FF10FE681EC8348E\MicrosoftServiceFabric.8.2.1363.9590.exe /AcceptEULA'. Process Id: 15288
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 8.2.1363' is '1'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 8.2.1363' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 8.2.1363 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK - 5.2.1363'. Skipping install
```

Looking at the **first** of the log files, I get this:

```
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,Extracting runtime cab to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.otwin05u.dde...
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,19.01.2022 12:16:15 Running Process: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MicrosoftServiceFabricAutoextractor.exe /L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.otwin05u.dde" /E /Y with timeout 01:00:00
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,Current Powershell Execution Policy: Unrestricted
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,Searching for legacy installation registry key.
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,Service Fabric Product not detected in registry.
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,Found legacy fabric files at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric. Start removal...
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,Executing powershell.exe with parameters: -NoProfile -Command & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\CleanFabric.ps1' -LogPath C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog.Uninstall_637781913748003856.log
19.01.2022 11:16:15,Info,19.01.2022 12:16:15 Running Process: powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\CleanFabric.ps1' -LogPath C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog.Uninstall_637781913748003856.log with timeout 00:10:00
19.01.2022 11:16:18,Error,Failed to uninstall Service Fabric through CleanFabric.ps1. ExitCode: 1. Find additional logs at: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog.Uninstall_637781913748003856.log.
19.01.2022 11:16:18,Error,Uninstallation hit an issue.
19.01.2022 11:16:18,Info,Cleaning temporary directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.otwin05u.dde
19.01.2022 11:16:21,Info,Successfully extracted cab file to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric.otwin05u.dde
Press enter to exit. Process will automatically close after 30 seconds.
```

I tried to locate the additional logs mentioned (`C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\FabricSetupLog.Uninstall_637781913748003856.log`), but no such log file exists at that location. The only log files I have been able to find are the ones referred to above (located under `c:\windows\Temp`).

I also tried following the "Direct download" link in the web installer (see below), but this only confirms that the Service Fabric Runtime is required first.

[image: 03_direct_download]
[image: 04_runtime_required]

Any tips that might help me track down the underlying issue here would be greatly appreciated.

**PS** (update after comment below)
I realize there appears to be an issue with files remaining from a previous installation. One of the log files mentions the folder `C:\program files\ServiceFabric`. This folder is indeed created when I try to install, but I have removed it manually before attempting again. I've done this multiple times, and restarted my PC between this and reinstallation attempts too, just to be sure. In short, I can't find any trace of Service Fabric, yet it still tells me that it is failing to uninstall. Just to be on the safe side, I've also tried removing Visual Studio completely too, in case there was some link/dependency on it somehow, but I still get the same result.

Comment: It looks like you have an existing installation that it's failing to remove? `Found legacy fabric files at ...`, try manually removing or renaming the folder it's searching: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric`

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I've already tried this. I've updated my question about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple of days, I finally managed to solve this myself.

### Short story

Part of the installation scripts (a PS1 script) stopped due to Powershell by default running in 32 bit instead of 64 bit. I was able to work through this by running various bits and pieces of the process manually in a PS7 admin console.

### Long story

The installation of the SF runtime simply stopped and timed out at one point. By looking at the relevant process under Task Manager, I was able to locate and run that specific installer directly from Powershell. Doing this didn't give me any more info, but at least I could see that it just stopped in the middle of a script, which appeared to be running, even though no resources (memory or cpu) were spent on it. Based on that, I guessed that the 32 / 64 bit issue might be a cause.

Note that this script was different from the installer itself - it was a script called from it, and which required the installer to have been run first. I was not able to change how the installer called PS and make it use a 64 bit version, but eventually I was able to solve it by:

- Running the SF runtime installer from version 7 of Powershell first (**as admin!**), and go on until the point at which it failed:

  `.\MicrosoftServiceFabric.8.2.1363.9590.exe /force /accepteula`
- Then re-run the specific script that failed with parameters similar to those I saw in the output from running the installer (note that I removed the LogPath param here, as it was not recognized as valid for some reason):

  `.\InstallFabric.ps1 -FAbricRootIsPreInstalled -AcceptEULA`

Once this was done, I was finally able to run the original Web Platform installer, which now only attempted to install the SDK (realizing that the required Runtime was already in place).

This seemed to work, but there was one more hurdle: For some reason SF was not able to set up and run a local cluster in the default location; there was an error message mentioning something about access rights. I wasn't able to read all of it, as it was cropped in a status-message that was only displayed over the status bar for a few seconds, and the logs it referred to were did not exist. In any case, I solved this by specifying a different directory for SF to run in - one I knew I had proper access to. Again, PowerShell 7 (as admin!) to the rescue:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\"

.\DevClusterSetup.ps1 -PathToClusterDataRoot "C:\MySfFolder\ServiceFabric\Dev" -PathToClusterLogRoot "C:\MySfFolder\ServiceFabric\Logs"
```

It was a huge relief when I could finally confirm that my five-node cluster had been successfully created and was up and running:

[image]

Comment: which is the location of this file? .\MicrosoftServiceFabric.8.2.1363.9590.exe and from where you can download it, I can install the SDK but can't see the runtime, had issues with my registry in the past because the runtime was not installed and needed to remove this entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ServiceFabric. After doing it. I can't see anymore the runtime

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, I wanted to upgrade my service fabric version, and when I uninstalled the current version from my computer my control panel it was still showing the runtime version but this time without the service fabric icon, every time I was installing another version of the SDK, it was updated but the runtime was missing.

My solution for this instead of going with the [Stand-Alone option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-standalone-create-service-fabric-cluster) which didn't fix my problem or with [regular setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#enable-powershell-script-execution) was:

1- Use chocolatey
2- Find on the chocolatey packages service fabric [service fabric package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/service-fabric)
3- Run the Powershell with admin rights and run command: **choco install service-fabric**

This will install the runtime for you + the SDK, if you have any issues with the SDK you can install it from chocolatey command as well **choco install service-fabric-sdk**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

In the end I manually downloaded the runtime installer (e.g. MicrosoftServiceFabric.8.2.1571.9590.exe) fromdirect download link in the release notes and run it with MicrosoftServiceFabric.8.2.1571.9590.exe /accepteula /force

When you're running the installer you can copy MicrosoftServiceFabricAutoextractor.exe from C:\Windows\Temp\ before the installer deletes it. Create "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric" if it doesn't exist already and then run MicrosoftServiceFabricAutoextractor.exe /E /Y from there to unpack the installation (this part is failing for me a lot though... if it fails, try using 7zip to unpack it instead).

After that, finish the install:
cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code"
.".\InstallFabric.ps1" -FabricRootIsPreInstalled -AcceptEULA -LogPath 'C:\InstallFabric.log'

Comment: This helps me, thanks!